# Merge and Left Justify a Range of Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, merge, range

I have VBA code to select a range of cells on the same row and then merge & left justify that selection.

I would like to enhance it to allow me to select a range or block of rows and perform the same action on each row in the range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Get the last populated row in the worksheet via [an auxiliary function](http://www.nijbo.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=14&Itemid=32).
2. Iterate over the rows, and for each row find the last column used via another auxiliary function.
3. Merge the resulting dynamically created selection and align left.

[Important note from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052510211033.aspx#MergeCells): Only the data in the upper-left cell of a range (range: Two or more cells on a sheet. The cells in a range can be adjacent or nonadjacent.) of selected cells will remain in the merged cell. Data in other cells of the selected range will be deleted.

```
Option Explicit

Sub merge_left_justify()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim last_col As Long

    last_row = find_last_row(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For i = 1 To last_row Step 1
        j = find_last_col(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet, i)
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, j)).Select
        Selection.Merge
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function find_last_row(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    Dim last_row
    last_row = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], _
        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
    find_last_row = last_row
End Function

Function find_last_col(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal row As Long)
    Dim last_col
    last_col = Cells(row, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
    find_last_col = last_col
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually to answer my own question, I played around with some code while looking for help and came up with this. Anyone see any issues with this?  Seems to work except I still have a problem with the IF statement that is supposed to ignore and not merge any row that is blank, so it's just commented out here.

```
Sub MergeLeft()

    Dim range As range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    ' Merge Macro
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A

    RowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
    For i = 1 To RowCount
       Set range = Selection.Rows(i)
       'If range(i) <> "" Then
       With range
          .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
          .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
          .WrapText = False
          .Orientation = 0
          .AddIndent = False
          .IndentLevel = 0
          .ShrinkToFit = False
          .ReadingOrder = xlContext
          .MergeCells = False
       End With
       range.Merge
       'End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Merge Across?  Its a built-in tool under the merge dropdown.  If you need to tweak the way Merge works you could also use .Merge(Across)